# ¿Como usar implode con arrays obtenidos de columnas Mariadb PHP?

Tags: php, base-de-datos, array, mariadb

Hola estoy tratando de regresar un array por cada columna de un query donde cumpla una condicion where, y a cada elemento del array de cada columna agregarle una ',' pero no encuentro como hacerlo les dejo mi codigo:

```
$sql = "SELECT producto, unidad, cantidad, fecha_de_embarque, notas, etiquetado FROM detalle WHERE orden_de_compra = :orden_de_compra "; 
    $query = $db->prepare($sql);

        $query->bindparam(':orden_de_compra', $orden_de_compra);


        $query->execute();


        $arreglo = $query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);//aqui es donde busco obtener un arreglo por columna, para despues agregarle las comas.

         $productos = $arreglo['producto'];
         $unidades = $arreglo['unidad'];
         $cantidades = $arreglo['cantidad'];
         $fecha_de_embarque = $arreglo['fecha_de_embarque'];
         $notas = $arreglo['notas'];
         $etiquetados = $arreglo['etiquetado'];


        $string_productos = implode(",", $productos);

             $string_unidades = implode(",", $unidades);
             $string_cantidades = implode(",", $cantidades);
                     $string_fechas = implode(",", $fecha_de_embarque);

             $string_notas = implode(",", $notas);
             $string_etiquetados = implode(",", $etiquetados);
```

Agradeceria mucho su ayuda, que estoy trabado con esto

Comment: Podrías imprimir el valor de alguno de los arreglos, ej `$arreglo['producto']`

Comment: `$query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)` no te va a devolver un array por columna, sino un array con toda la fila (row) del registro actual. Para obtener todas los valores de cada columna y guardarlos en un array, deberías "iterar" sobre $arreglo con un `foreach` por ejemplo, e ir almacenando cada valor en una variable para tal caso.

Answer (score 1):

Como te he comentado, el uso de únicamete `fetch_all` aquí no es suficiente para lograr tu objetivo. Además tendrías que hacer lo siguiente:

```
<?php 
$sql = "SELECT producto, unidad, cantidad, fecha_de_embarque, notas, etiquetado FROM detalle WHERE orden_de_compra = :orden_de_compra "; 
$query = $db->prepare($sql);

$query->bindparam(':orden_de_compra', $orden_de_compra);


$query->execute();


$filas = $query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

$productos = [];
$unidades = [];
$cantidades = [];
$fecha_de_embarque = [];
$notas = [];
$etiquetados = [];

foreach ($filas as $arreglo) {
    $productos[] = $arreglo['producto'];
    $unidades[] = $arreglo['unidad'];
    $cantidades[] = $arreglo['cantidad'];
    $fecha_de_embarque[] = $arreglo['fecha_de_embarque'];
    $notas[] = $arreglo['notas'];
    $etiquetados[] = $arreglo['etiquetado'];
}


$string_productos = implode(",", $productos);

$string_unidades = implode(",", $unidades);
$string_cantidades = implode(",", $cantidades);
$string_fechas = implode(",", $fecha_de_embarque);

$string_notas = implode(",", $notas);
$string_etiquetados = implode(",", $etiquetados);

echo $string_productos;
echo $string_unidades;
echo $string_fechas;
echo $string_notas;
echo $string_etiquetados;
```

Ahora sí estamos procesando todos los resultados obtenidos desde base de datos y organizándolos en arrays (arreglos) para cumplir con nuestro propósito.

Comment: gracias por compartir tu codigo me funciona perfecto!